# IServiceCollection override a single constructor argument

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a class that takes three constructor arguments. In my composition root I want to define/override only **one** of the three constructor arguments; the other two dependencies have already been mapped in my DI container and should get created from the IServiceProvider.

With Ninject I could do something like this:

```
Bind<IMyInterface>().To<MyClass>()    
    .WithConstructorArgument("constructorArgumentName", x => "constructor argument value");
```

When Ninject creates MyClass it uses this string parameter and automatically injects the other two dependencies for me. The problem I'm experiencing in .net core is that I cannot tell the IServiceCollection I only want to specify one of the three arguments, I have to define all of them or none. For example, in .net core this is what I have to do:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyInterface>(x=> new MyClass("constructor argument value", new Dependency2(), new Dependency3());
```

I don't like having to create new instances of the Dependency2 and Dependency3 classes; these two classes could have their own constructor arguments. I just want the DI to manage those dependencies. So my question is - how do you override a single constructor argument when mapping dependencies in .net core using the IServiceCollection class?

If you can't override just a single contructor argument then how do you resolve a dependency with the IServiceCollection? I tried doing something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyInterface>(x=> new MyClass("constructor argument value", serviceCollection.Resolve<IDependency2>(), serviceCollection.Resolve(IDependency3>());
```

But this didn't work, and I couldn't figure out how to resolve dependencies using the IServiceCollection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
services.AddTransient<IDependency2, Dependency2Impl>();

services.AddTransient<IDependency3, Dependency3Impl>();

services.AddTransient<IMyInterface>(provider=>
    return new MyClass("constructor argument value",
      provider.GetService<IDependency2>(),
      provider.GetService<IDependency3>());
);
```

Comment: You have a 'provider' class there but I don't see what that is or where its coming from? My above code sits in the Startup.cs class in a method with this signature: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services). Where is the 'provider' class being created?

Comment: `provider` is `Func` parameter and its type is `IServiceProvider`. In your question you defined it as 'x'.

Comment: Oh I see. I completely overlooked that :). Thank you, works great!

Comment: I was looking for a .NET Core alternative to AutoFac's RegisterInstance where you can register an instance taking constructor arguments, this seems to fit the bill

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants a generic but flexible solution: https://gist.github.com/ReallyLiri/c669c60db2109554d5ce47e03613a7a9

The API is

```cs
public static void AddSingletonWithConstructorParams<TService, TImplementation>(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            object paramsWithNames
        );
public static void AddSingletonWithConstructorParams(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Type serviceType,
            Type implementationType,
            object paramsWithNames
        );
public static void AddSingletonWithConstructorParams<TService, TImplementation>(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            params object[] parameters
        );
public static void AddSingletonWithConstructorParams(
            this IServiceCollection services,
            Type serviceType,
            Type implementationType,
            params object[] parameters
        );
```

Implemented with constructor method reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
Service Cons.:

```
public SkillsService(IRepositoryBase<FeatureCategory> repositoryCategory, int categoryId)
```

Startup:

```
 services.AddScoped<ISkillsService>(i => new SkillsService(services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IRepositoryBase<FeatureCategory>>(), AppSettingsFeatures.Skills));
```